# Как решить проблему с поиском ближайших врагов?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

есть скрипт и есть проблема. Нашел скрипт на просторах интернета. Скрипт определяет какой враг ближе всего находится к игроку. Но если происходит Destroy любого врага, unity выдает ошибку

MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

```
GameObject[] enemy;
GameObject closest;

public string nearest;

void Start()
{
    enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
}

GameObject FindClosestEnemies()
{
    float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    foreach (GameObject go in enemy)
    {
        Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
        float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
        if (curDistance < distance)
        {
            closest = go;
            distance = curDistance;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}

void Update()
{
    nearest = FindClosestEnemies().name;
}
```

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки, включая номер строки, в которой выходит ошибка.

Comment: ошибка на строке 17: Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position; так же ошибка в Update: FindClosestEnemy.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/FindClosestEnemy.cs:34)

Comment: Второй вопрос лучше оформить подробно и отдельно, в данный момент он слишком пространный и никто не сможет дать на него ответа.

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. список врагов в этом примере формируется лишь один раз в самом начале, ничего странного, что после `Destroy()` любого из врагов генерируется ошибка. Список врагов надо держать актуальным, а сейчас получается, что после уничтожения врага, из массива он не удаляется.

Быстрое решение, которое вам подойдет, раз вам подходят скрипты из интернета. В реальной жизни никогда не стоит делать `FindGameObjectsWithTag`, нигде и никогда, просто забыть о нем, но раз такое дело, почему бы и нет.

```
GameObject[] enemy;
GameObject closest;

public string nearest;

GameObject FindClosestEnemies()
{
    float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    foreach (GameObject go in enemy)
    {
        Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
        float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
        if (curDistance < distance)
        {
            closest = go;
            distance = curDistance;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}

void Update()
{
    enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
    nearest = FindClosestEnemies().name;
}
```

В идеале, превратите этот скрипт в манагер врагов, поддерживайте актуальность списка врагов, и вообще делайте с ними все, что захотите, вроде такого:

```
List<GameObject> enemies = new List<GameObject>();

public void AddEnemy(GameObject enemy){
    enemies.Add(enemy);
}

public void RemoveEnemy(GameObject enemy){
    enemies.Remove(enemy);
}

public GameObject FindClosestEnemies(Transform position) {
    GameObject closest;
    float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    foreach (GameObject go in enemies )
    {
        Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
        float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
        if (curDistance < distance)
        {
            closest = go;
            distance = curDistance;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я знаю, что FindGameObjectsWithTag применять нельзя, тем более в Update, может есть какая-нибудь альтернатива?

Comment: Обновил ответ, альтернатива это продумать архитектуру игры.

Comment: ой, извиняюсь, не увидел продолжения, большое спасибо!